# how to declare a generic class in c++

Tags: c++, generics

My main question is: can I put the `generic` type before a `class` definition?

Like, can I do something like this:

```
generic class Classname (ParameterType parameter)
{
     cout << "Hello world";
}
```

Comment: What is this "`generic` type"? Is `generic` supposed to be a keyword? (It's not a keyword in C++.)

Comment: related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Your question is unclear.    What do you mean by a "generic" type?  What do you expect to be able to do with such a type?   Without such clarification - in your question - there is no way to judge if any answer given is useful or even relevant.

Comment: Your code snippet looks like a function, not a class. A class has no parameters and no function body.

Answer (score 3):

Templates are the way to do generics in C++. You can write it like this:

```
template<class ItemType> class ClassName
{
public:
   ClassName(const ItemType& newdata) : data(newdata) {}
private:
   ItemType data;
};
```

Later on in main:

```
ClassName<int> data1(1);
ClassName<char> data2('A');
```

Comment: While what you say here is correct, the original question is so unclear, it is not possible to even determine if this answer addresses the question.

Comment: I know. I am just giving him an example of what generics looks like in C++.